# Mark Joshi Quantitative finance numerical techiniques, writting an algorithm that produces a random variable

Tags: programming, finance-mathematics, quantitative

**Background:**

I am preparing for interviews and I was told to try and answer as many problems in the Mark Joshi book as possible.

**Question:**

> Suppose an asset takes values from a discrete set $v_j$ and the probabilities of $v_j$ is $p_j$.
>   Write an algorithm that produces the random variable for this asset from a uniformly distributed random variable

I am not sure if I understand the question posed here. Any suggestions or clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if @MarkJoshi will chime in...

Comment: Also, calculate the probability that your future employer is reading this post. ;)

Comment: @vanguard2k haha don't scare me like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Mark Joshi's book is a good preparation.

For this question you are given some function *random()* yielding a uniform random number and what we want is a function *next()* which yields realizations of a random $X$ variable with values $v_j$ such that $P(X=v_j)=p_j$.

From standard textbooks we know the following transformation: If $u_i$ are uniform random numbers and $g$ the inverse of a cumulative distribution function $F$ then $g(u_i)$ are realizations of a random variable with c.d.f $F$.

In our case the best way is to store the values in a vector $v[]$ so we have just to handle the random index $Y$ with $P(Y=j)=p_j$. The c.d.f is given by
$$
  F[k] = P(Y\le k) = \sum_{j \le k} p_j
$$
and can be stored in another array, Now the inverse is easy to implement:

```
int g(double x)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < F.Length; k++)
    {
        if (x <= F[k])
        return k;
    }
    return F.Length - 1; // you're not getting here
}
```

and

```
double next()
{
    return v[g[random()]];
}
```

Done. The transform can as well be used to generate normal, exponential... random numbers.

Comment: As I understand I first create a vector of uniform random numbers of size $n-1$ then I create a function cdf $F$ (I used normal CDF). Then I create a function $g$ that computes the inverse of $F$?

Comment: You can create a vector or call the function repeatedly as implemented above. Best way is to directly implement $g$ (the inverse of $F$). For the normal distribution code for the inverse c.d.f. exists (e.g. Numerical Recipees) and for the exponential it's easy to write down analytically.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you have seen the $n=2$ case:

Write a program that returns "Yes" with probability p and "No" otherwise. You are given a function runif(), which returns a random number between 0 and 1.

Solution:

r = runif(); if $r<p$ then return "YES"; else return "NO".

From this well known example you have to generalize to more than 2 possible outcomes. Imagine that you have to simulate a lottery spinning wheel with unequal sectors. of width $p_1,p_2,\cdots$ with $r$ representing the distance (fraction of a circle) by which the wheel turned.

Solution:

After you draw a uniform random number r=runif(), you check its value. If $r<p_1$ you return $v_1$, else if $r<p1+p2$ you return $v_2$ else if $r<p_1+p_2+p_3$ you return $v_3$,... The general case, for arbitrary $n$, is just a simple loop testing if $r$ is in the right range and returning the corresponding value for that sector. (Do you think you can write the code?).

Comment: is $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ uniform random numbers from $0$ to $1$ as well?

Comment: $p_1,p_2,\cdots$ are the given probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above which suggest simulating uniform $U\sim(0,1)$ and returning $J$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{J-1} p_i \le U < \sum_{i=1}^{J} p_i$ will be fine for the interview.  However, since this isn't just a job interview Q&A site, I'd like to remark that for large sample spaces, or if you make a lot of samples from even a modestly sized sample spaces, this is extremely inefficient. I'd be aghast to see this being used in production code in the 21st century for these cases- [Walker alias sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method), for example, is a much better alternative.

Comment: if you're given the pdf (as in the question), then why not use the inverse transform method?

Comment: @will - as I mentioned, it is inefficient in general.  If the $p_j$ have a special form that allows you to invert the CDF then, sure, awesome- do that.  Or, as your answer alludes to, you could *approximately* invert the CDF by e.g. fitting splines... as long as you're happy with *approximate* simulation (often we are, but that's *not* the question here).  All I'm saying is that repeatedly adding up a bunch of numbers isn't that smart.

Comment: I would disagree that it is inefficient. Perhaps less accurate, but efficiency is not even remotely a concern-that is all inside your spline code, which you can get extremely efficient...

Comment: I think we have different definitions of efficient and different use cases in mind (your idea of efficient sounds like "it's fast on all the examples I tried", which is fine, of course).

Comment: Maybe you're talking about efficacy then? Efficiency wise, you're not repeatedly adding up numbers, as you only construct the spline once.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency

Comment: Look, I'm clearly not commenting on the efficiency of a particular algorithm for inverting a CDF (e.g. spline in your case, sure it has a lower cost of evaluation, like the alias methods I mention) and not saying in some cases it is good- merely stating that in general this approach is not an efficient approach for exact simulation, which somehow you appear to have missed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61810/discussion-between-p-windridge-and-will).

Comment: I have not missed it, I just disagree that any of these methods are exact, as you will have a sampling error. If you want to then say "but if we take the limit..." then they both become exact, but obviously efficiency is not so great.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking you to produce an algorithm to generate random numbers with a given probability distribution, having been provided with uniformly distributed random numbers.

essentially, you need to provide some function, $f(\phi(\ldots)): \tilde{X}\sim U(0,1) \to \tilde{Y} \sim \phi(\ldots)$ . That is, a function of a pdf, that will convert uniformly distributed random numbers to random numbers distributed according to the pdf provided.

There are several ways to do it described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling#Continuous_distributions), in the case of this specific question, the one you want is [inverse transform sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). You just need to integrate the pdf to get a cdf to use. You can then create an interpolating spline for it, on some grid, and then swap x and y to invert it.